# is there anyway to vertically align the boxes in google org chart visualization

Tags: jquery, google-visualization, orgchart, organizational-chart

i am using [google org chart visualization API](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/orgchart.html#customproperties) and i want to have the vertical alignment set to top on the cells. (i am showing multiple people in each org chart box so i want every "level" to align to the top instead of the middle.  So in the example, where you have **Alice** which is vertically centered. i want it to valign="top".  is this possible to do using the google visualization api ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can style the elements within the Org Chart.
Here's how I did it...

My mistake at first was to add the css block above the Google Javascript code. Once I moved it down, I could change pretty much any visual property.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['orgchart']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {

        /*GOOGLE MUMBO JUMBO GOES HERE*/

        var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, {allowHtml:true});
      }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .google-visualization-orgchart-node {
        width: 240px;
    }
    .google-visualization-orgchart-node-medium {
        vertical-align: top;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for a simple, open-source Javascript Organizational Chart library:

I've just published lib_gg_orgchart. It uses a JSON input and draws the chart using Raphael.

Take a look at the site for some examples and download:

http://www.fluxus.com.ve/gorka/lib_gg_orgchart

If you find it useful, please let me know.

Comment: New web home for lib_gg_orgchart is http://librerias.logicas.org/lib_gg_orgchart. New version will come soon, fixing some bugs and integrating collaborator's changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a simple way to do that with Google API but you can achieve that with simple CSS;

Instead of

```
['Alice', 'Mike', ''],
```

you can write

```
['<div style="height:50px;vertical-align:top">Alice</div>', 'Mike', ''],
```

If you want, you can also write a JavaScript code to calculate that cell's height and assign it to that cell's div tag.

**EDIT:** If you want to vertically align the TD element, you can write a custom CSS;

```
.google-visualization-orgchart-node {vertical-align:top;}
```

Comment: isn't that vertically aligning within the div (not within the table itself) ??

Comment: Yes it's aligning the div. But if you don't want to vertically align the div but the TD element then you can write a custom CSS;  .google-visualization-orgchart-node {vertical-align:top;}

Answer (score -1):

Elzo had a suggestion but instead of using valign: top; you need to use 
vertical-align: top
like below

`data.setProperty(0, 0, "style", "vertical-align:top;");`

Answer (score -2):

You can adjust CSS by cell with [setProperty](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/reference.html#DataTable_setProperty) function:

```
// for 0 row 0 column
data.setProperty(0, 0, "style", "valign:top;");
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to make any difference